# Using "Get all latest" function of Enterprise-Architect outside of the EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to acces the EA function "Get All Latest" for a package of the EAP file outside of a running Enterprise architect.

For example via a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods in the Object Model API are available to any COM client, so yes. I usually write my code in C#, but you can get it to work in a script as well if you prefer.

`EA.Repository`, the basic EA interaction class, has a `ShowWindow()` method which you can use to control whether or not the main window is displayed.

Version control functions are available through the `EA.Package.VersionControl*()` methods.

Comment: Though "outside" means you need to open an instance of EA in your batch.

Comment: Thanks this already helps. So using C#  how would the code look to open EA and call this functionality? As I see it the VersionControl*() methodes only have the getLatest function. So do I need to Open EA and iterate over all packages there, then look if they are version controlled and then call the EA.Package.VersionControlGetLatest () function?